# Android Play store upload apk production error

Tags: android, google-play

Hi guys I was trying to upload apk for production however I got this error message: "You don't have rights to modify the application."

I was invited by as a user in the team. I'm guessing that it has something to do with that? Anyone here experienced the same error?

Comment: I a very similar problem. The owner of the account claims that I have "Manage Alpha & Beta APKs". And this is supported by the fact that I CAN click the buttons and start/manage a new release (only for Alpha/Beta). However, when I actually upload an APK, I get this error: "Upload failed
  You don't have rights to modify the application."

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but was a configuration problem

Be sure you have rights ... 
"Manage production APKs" checked

[image: Revision 1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify user rights from settings. Check that "Manage production APKs" is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload an APK for another account you need one of these:

- Manage Production APKs
- Manage Alpha & Beta APKs

In case this is the first APK that's being uploaded for this app, then you will also need the permission:

- **Create & edit draft apps**